# Make buttons unresizable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jbutton

So I was trying to google how to set a default size to JButtons so that they don't grow as the JFrame is resized. I didn't see a setDefaultSize method but the closest one I could find that does a similar job is setMaximumSize(). However, it doesn't seem to work in my situation and I'm guessing it's because I'm using Grid Layout for positioning my buttons in the frame, here's a small piece of my code:

```
rightPanel.add(ButtonA);
rightPanel.add(ButtonB);
rightPanel.add(ButtonC);

outerPanel.add(leftPanel);
outerPanel.add(rightPanel);
getContentPane().add(outerPanel);
```

Here's a picture of what happens:

[image]

I would also like to have my buttons in the middle of the right panel when I'm resizing (just like they are now but a lot smaller). Any idea of how I can fix this? I'm assuming that I have to use another layout or something.

Thanks

EDIT: I modified my code to use BoxLayout but it does not seem to put the buttons in the middle. The X Alignment is working but Y Alignment is not doing anything:

```
ButtonA.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
ButtonA.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

ButtonB.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
ButtonB.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

ButtonC.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
ButtonC.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

rightPanel.add(ButtonA);
rightPanel.add(ButtonB);
rightPanel.add(ButtonC);

outerPanel.add(leftPanel);
outerPanel.add(rightPanel);
getContentPane().add(outerPanel);
```

[image]

EDIT2: Fixed with vertical glue.

Comment: Yes, `GridLayout` is the wrong choice.  Did you try any of the other layout managers?  There are a few options that will work.  I advise experimenting a little.

Comment: Yes, if you check my EDIT, I tried using BoxLayout but I can't manage to align my buttons to be in the middle of the panel (see pic in OP).

Comment: :-) Sorry, I didn't see your edit when I made my earlier comment.  I would try putting vertical glue above and below the buttons, if you're trying to move the cluster of buttons down to the middle.  Have a look at the link in camickr's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GridLayout will always resize the components to fill the space available.

Try using a vertical `BoxLayout`instead. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks man, could you tell me why my buttons are not aligned in the middle when I'm using Box Layout? See my EDIT in the post.

Comment: @user3281466, read the tutorial. There is a section that explains how alignment works. You probably need "glue" before/after your components.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate each JButton in a JPanel with a FlowLayout, and then add those FlowLayout JPanels to the rightPanel instead of the JButtons themselves. This will allow you to keep your evenly spaced buttons, but won't make them expand to take up the entire space that the parent container has available.

If you don't want them evenly spaced, but to be three consecutive buttons one after another top down, you can make the right panel have a BorderLayout, add a sub panel to the north area of the BorderLayout with the original GridLayout that the right panel had, and then add those FlowLayout panels containing the JButtons.